# Strange behavior with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I have an error in my code, I'd like my processes to exit, but I have some strange behavior that I don't know how to work around.

This code errors out and closes the processes as expected:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def worker(queue):
    raise error

task_queue = Queue(10)

the_pool = Pool(1, worker, (task_queue,))
```

But this one spins off an infinite number of new processes which all error out (but followed up by yet new processes):

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Pool

def worker(queue):
    raise error

task_queue = Queue(10)

the_pool = Pool(1, worker, (task_queue,))

while True: # <-- added this
    pass
```

How can I effectively stop the second from spinning off infinite new processes?

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? Particularly, what should attempts to interact with the broken process pool do? (The obvious solution is "fix `worker`".)

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, I simply expect that the single process allotted to pool will encounter the error then quit. If I then encounter the infinite loop below, that doesn't matter. I just don't see how the infinite loop can interact at all with the above pool.

Comment: The pool has a daemon thread in an infinite loop to clean up and replace exited workers. That thread keeps going until the pool is closed or all non-daemon threads exit, so the `while True: pass` keeps it alive.

Comment: Interesting, I think I understand. Is there any way I can keep the daemon from replacing workers, so that if my workers all error out the pool then quits?